# how to write program that takes a number as its argument and return the sum of 1+2+.. up to argument?

Tags: c

how to write program that takes a number as its argument and return the sum of 1+2+.. up to argument?

I can't get the codes right. Can somebody help me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>                                                               
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
int i;
int sum =0;

if(argc !=2){
 printf("usage: %s <count> \n", argv[0]);
 exit(n);
 }

for(i=1; i<=atoi(argv[1]); i++){
 sum+=i;
}
```

Comment: what's the error? you're missing a trailing '}' at the end of the program.

Comment: For the most part, your code and logic looks right, aside from not closing your `main` function with a `}` at the end (and also no `return` statement at the end though a C99 compiler will implicitly put `return 0` in anyway). What isn't working? Can't compile?

Comment: @PrototypeStark, Not to mention something that prints the sum.

Comment: use the formula `Sum = n * ( n + 1) / 2` instead for efficiency.

Comment: So far so good ... you need to define `n` though.

Comment: @SparKot I suspect the point is rather to get familiar with loops than efficiency. Otherwise, I agree.

Comment: And what @SparKot mentioned is a formula derived from [arithmetic series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html), and also known as one of the Gauss Summation formulas (for calculating the sum of a positive series of integers from `1...n`.

Comment: it will not enter the for() loop @overloading

Comment: The homework tag is obsolete? Why?

Comment: @Cthulhu, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: Oh, and by the way, use `strtol` instead of `atoi`. With the latter, you have no idea if an error occurred while converting.

Comment: I might have to downvote this question if the questioner doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: @OP, The only reason you wouldn't enter the loop provided you supply one argument is that `n` isn't declared (assuming you have the few missing lines at the end present in your code).

Comment: The formula provided is correct, but nobody has compensated for integer overflow, meaning that it is not as accurate as the loop when used verbatim.  I have answered accordingly, for those who are interested. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to answer your question.

You need to actually output the result.  Something like:

```
printf("%d\n", sum);
```

Or return it to whoever called the program, although that is a little unusual:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    ...
    return sum;
}
```

But I am providing my own answer here because there is a good reason to consider doing this in a loop...  At least until you've thought about it a bit more.

Namely, the formula `(n * (n+1)) / 2` will overflow 32-bit integers and produce the wrong answer when `n` becomes 65536 or greater.  But the 32-bit integer can itself store a sum up to `n <= 92681`.  That means the formula by itself produces the wrong answer for roughly 30% of the solution space.

So you might think you need to loop, but there's a little trick here.  Because the formula uses both `n` and `n+1`, you can guarantee that one of those numbers is evenly divisible by 2.  And therefore you can do it like this:

```
unsigned long n;
unsigned long sum;

n = atoi(argv[1]);

if( n == 0 || n > 92681 ) {
    printf( "The supplied value (%u) is out of range\n", n );
} else {
    if( (n % 2) == 0 ) {
        sum = (n / 2) * (n+1);
    } else {
        sum = n * ((n+1) / 2);
    }
    printf( "Sum from 1 to %u is %u\n", n, sum );
}
```

Now you have a simple formula that produces the same answer as the loop, at least for all values of `n` that don't lead to overflowing the sum.

Comment: For fiddly reasons, it turns out that another equivalent formula is `(n | 1) * ((n + 1) / 2)`, which avoids overflow, branching *and* readability. Personally I don't think that's worth the comment I'd have to write to explain it, but there it is :-)

Comment: Ahhhh that's real clever.  Nice one, cheers! =)

Comment: Note that your limits are for _unsigned_ 32-bit integers, for signed integers, the numbers would be 46341 and 65535.

Comment: Correct.  I didn't see any reason to consider signed integers when I was talking about maximimizing the valid solution space.  But you have a point: I should have explicitly mentioned it, because the question was using signed (well, if their compiler defaulted to signed)

Comment: For `int`, there is no default, that is signed per the standard, only `char` leaves the choice to the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>                                                               
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    int i;
    int sum =0;

    if(argc !=2){
        printf("usage: %s <count> \n", argv[0]);
        exit(n);
    }
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    sum = (n*(n+1))/2; // formula of sum of first n numbers
}
```

Comment: I don't think the formula change really constitutes an answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a loop. You can use the simple formula,

> int sum = (n * (n + 1)) / 2
>
> Where n will be your input.

output will be the summation of each digit starting from your input to 1 decreasing by 1 - same as your loop.