# C, while adding number each run

Tags: c, while-loop

Hello fairly new at coding, i have this program which should add a number each time the program is run, it computes 1 + 2 + 3 +......(n - 1) + n 
and an if statement that compares the value to (n*(n+1))/2 and then displays a message if its the same or different.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

  int value = 0, n_data_value, count = 0, second_value;

  printf("Enter a number\n");
  scanf("%lf", &n_data_value);

  while (count < 10) {
   value = (1 + value) + (n_data_value - 1) + n_data_value;
   printf("%f\n", value);
   second_value = (n_data_value * (n_data_value + 1))/2;
   printf("The number is %f\n", value);
   count = count + 1;

   if(value = second_value){
     printf("value = %f and second_value = %f", value, second_value);
   }
  } 
 return 0;
}
```

When i run it i just get this

> Enter a number 3
>
> 0.000000
>
> The number is 0.000000
>
> 0.000000
>
> The number is 0.000000
>
> 0.000000
>
> The number is 0.000000
>
> 0.000000
>
> The number is 0.000000
>
> 0.000000
>
> The number is 0.000000
>
> 0.000000
>
> The number is 0.000000
>
> 0.000000
>
> The number is 0.000000
>
> 0.000000
>
> The number is 0.000000
>
> 0.000000
>
> The number is 0.000000
>
> 0.000000
>
> The number is 0.000000

Comment: When you get your program working and fix your loop logic and maths, you'll find a disparity between the formula and your looped value after `N=65535`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923523/how-to-write-program-that-takes-a-number-as-its-argument-and-return-the-sum-of-1/12924209#12924209

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it more than 1 time : just add something like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

   int value = 0, n_data_value, count = 1, second_value;
   char char_quit='';

   do //Infinite loop
   {

      printf("Enter a number\n");
      scanf("%d", &n_data_value);

      while (count <= n_data_value) {//while loop to calculate 1+2+3+...+n
        value = value + count;
        count = count + 1;
      }
     second_value = (n_data_value * (n_data_value + 1))/2;//calculates n(n+1)/2
     printf("The number is %d\n", second_value);

     if(value == second_value)//compares value
     {
        printf("value = %d and second_value = %d", value, second_value);
     } 

     //Ask to continue ?
     printf("Do you want to continue ? Y/N \n"); //Y or any other key will force to continue the program
     scanf("%c", &char_quit );

  }while (char_quit == 'n' || char_quit == 'N');

  return 0;
}
```

You could naturally use something like : while(1) insteand of the "do while" if you want an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%d` with `int` variables in `scanf`/`printf`.

`%lf` is for `double` values.

Answer (score 1):

The test for `value` matching `second_value` is also wrong.  Use `==` to test for equality

i.e. change

```
if(value = second_value){
```

to

```
if(value == second_value){
```

Note that compiling with warnings enabled (`-Wall` for gcc, `/W4` for msvc) would have flagged this up for you.

Comment: Hmm how do i enable warnings in the compiler? just add -wall or? :)

Comment: If you're compiling from the command line, add -Wall for gcc or /W4 for msvc.  If you're using an IDE, there will be a build settings dialog which accepts compiler flags

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

  int value = 0, n_data_value, count = 1, second_value;

  printf("Enter a number\n");
  scanf("%d", &n_data_value);

  while (count <= n_data_value) {//while loop to calculate 1+2+3+...+n
   value = value + count;
   count = count + 1;
  }
  second_value = (n_data_value * (n_data_value + 1))/2;//calculates n(n+1)/2
  printf("The number is %d\n", second_value);

 if(value == second_value){//compares value
     printf("value = %d and second_value = %d", value, second_value);
   } 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes that works, but what if i wanted to run the program more times? :)